# Converting a Korean string to English string

Tags: c#

Hi i have a program which reads a sequence from  a server . I want to change the Korean string for gender to English

This is what i tried

```
recvMsg = sock.getResponse(ConnSocket.OVERHIT_GET_AVERAGE_OF_AGE, sendMsg);
string[] avers = recvMsg.Split('&');
readSexAOA.Text = avers[0];

// try changing sex here
if (avers[0] == "남")
{
    avers[0] ="M";
}

if (avers[0] == "여")
{
    avers[0] = "F";
}
```

But the output still remains a korean string even though it enters the IF condition .

Comment: Is the avers[0] shows the correct Korean character?

Comment: Try putting `readSexAOA.Text = avers[0];` last, after you've changed the characters.

Comment: Looks like you're translating from Korean to English after assigning the Korean version to readSexAOA.Text.  Is that intentional?

Comment: @adv12 : Yes it is intentional

Comment: Have you tried using unicode values for the Korean and English characters?